# Calculating time elapsed on a groupby object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have some time series data which I want to separate out by category, and further separate when a binary value == 1. I want to calculate the time elapsed per day when the binary value == 1.

Here is the original data sample:

```
                       category  binary
utctime                                               
2014-10-23 13:15:08           a   0
2014-10-24 16:09:13           b   0
2014-10-24 18:56:01           a   1
2014-10-24 21:42:42           a   1
2014-10-25 00:29:22           a   0
2014-10-25 03:16:02           c   1
2014-10-25 06:02:43           c   1
2014-10-25 08:49:23           c   0
2014-10-25 11:36:03           c   1
2014-10-25 14:22:43           c   1
2014-10-25 17:09:24           d   0
2014-10-25 19:56:05           b   0
2014-10-25 22:42:45           b   0
2014-10-26 01:29:26           e   0
2014-10-26 04:16:15           d   0
2014-10-26 07:02:56           e   1
2014-10-26 09:49:36           e   1
2014-10-26 12:36:16           e   0
2014-10-26 15:22:57           e   0
2014-10-26 18:09:46           d   0
2014-10-26 20:56:26           b   0
2014-10-26 23:43:07           e   0
```

I started off by filtering the binary column, then grouping by category, but I lose the date index. If I group by index.date (or pd.date_grouper), I don't know how to subgroup into the separate categories.

It feels like the data may be in a particularly unhelpful shape, but I don't know how to make it better - I tried a pivot table with the categories as columns, but since utctimes are unique to categories, that didn't work. Should I take utctime out of the index?

The desired output would be something akin to the following:

```
category a   
date              total time binary == 1
2014-10-23          10 minutes
2014-10-24          5 minutes

category b   
date              total time binary == 1
2014-10-23          1 minutes
2014-10-24          15 minutes
```

Comment: What is the desired result for the example you gave?

Comment: @unutbu I've added a possible desired output, but like I say, I'm not sure if the datashape is particularly helpful to get me there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @unutbu data & setup

Add in an extra column that we want to diff as well

```
In [31]: df2['ts'] = df2.index

In [32]: df2
Out[32]: 
                    category  temp  binary                  ts
2014-10-24 18:56:01        a  23.3       1 2014-10-24 18:56:01
2014-10-24 21:42:42        a  23.0       1 2014-10-24 21:42:42
2014-10-25 03:16:02        c  23.1       1 2014-10-25 03:16:02
2014-10-25 06:02:43        c  22.8       1 2014-10-25 06:02:43
2014-10-25 08:49:23        c  23.7       1 2014-10-25 08:49:23
2014-10-26 07:02:56        e  22.4       1 2014-10-26 07:02:56
2014-10-26 09:49:36        e  22.7       1 2014-10-26 09:49:36
```

A slightly more general way of grouping

```
In [33]: g = df2.groupby(['category',pd.Grouper(freq='D',level=0)])
```

This will be much more performant, though YMMV.

```
In [34]: g.last()-g.first()
Out[34]: 
                     temp  binary       ts
category                                  
a        2014-10-24  -0.3       0 02:46:41
c        2014-10-25   0.6       0 05:33:21
e        2014-10-26   0.3       0 02:46:40

In [35]: result = g.last()-g.first()                   

In [46]: result['ts'] = result['ts'] / Timedelta('1m')

In [47]: result
Out[47]: 
                     temp  binary          ts
category                                     
a        2014-10-24  -0.3       0  166.683333
c        2014-10-25   0.6       0  333.350000
e        2014-10-26   0.3       0  166.666667
```

Comment: I'd thrown together the binary column without thinking about it's values, and applying it to the real set throws up a further complication: Suppose the binary is on for a time, then off, then back on within one day, doing the difference of .last() - .first() is no longer an accurate answer. I've changed my original post to reflect this (look at 2014-10-25 category c)

Comment: add the binary flag with your grouper, or group at a lower freq. not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. Essentially, the binary column tells me that a switch is on; my db is updated periodically (minute by minute roughly) and I want to see how long it has been switched on altogether in a 24h period. So if I look at category a for a specific date, I want to select the periods with that date where the switch is on - my utctime just indicates when the message was sent. Currently the answers provide the time elapsed between "first on message" and "last on message" in a day, but ignore any "off" messages between them?

Comment: see the recipe at the end of the section [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping); this is called section grouping. best prob to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

To group by category and index date, you could use

```
date = df2.index.date
grouped = df2.groupby(['category', date])
```

Note that groupby can accept a list containing both a string and an array.  The
string refers to a column name, while the array acts as a proxy for a virtual
column. The `date`s are not a column of `df2` and yet you can group by them. Pretty cool, huh?

To find the total number of minutes in each group you could aggregate using a lambda function such as

```
lambda x: (x.index[-1]-x.index[0])/pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')
```

`(x.index[-1]-x.index[0])` calculates the difference between the first and last timestamp in each group. Note this assumes the index is in sorted order.
The difference `(x.index[-1]-x.index[0])` returns a `pd.Timedelta`.
Dividing by `pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')` returns the total number of minutes.

Note that [Jeff's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142175/190597), which uses `g.last()-g.first()`, is likely to be much faster for large DataFrames since it computes all the Timedeltas in one vectorized operation instead of computing each Timedelta with one lambda function call for each row.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['2014-10-23 13:15:08', 'a', 999.9, 0],
     ['2014-10-24 16:09:13', 'b', 24.1, 0],
     ['2014-10-24 18:56:01', 'a', 23.3, 1],
     ['2014-10-24 21:42:42', 'a', 23.0, 1],
     ['2014-10-25 00:29:22', 'a', 22.7, 0],
     ['2014-10-25 03:16:02', 'c', 23.1, 1],
     ['2014-10-25 06:02:43', 'c', 22.8, 1],
     ['2014-10-25 08:49:23', 'c', 23.7, 1],
     ['2014-10-25 11:36:03', 'c', 24.8, 0],
     ['2014-10-25 14:22:43', 'c', 25.7, 0],
     ['2014-10-25 17:09:24', 'd', 24.9, 0],
     ['2014-10-25 19:56:05', 'b', 24.6, 0],
     ['2014-10-25 22:42:45', 'b', 24.2, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 01:29:26', 'e', 22.7, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 04:16:15', 'd', 23.6, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 07:02:56', 'e', 22.4, 1],
     ['2014-10-26 09:49:36', 'e', 22.7, 1],
     ['2014-10-26 12:36:16', 'e', 22.2, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 15:22:57', 'e', 23.1, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 18:09:46', 'd', 23.8, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 20:56:26', 'b', 23.8, 0],
     ['2014-10-26 23:43:07', 'e', 22.7, 0]], 
    columns=['utctime', 'category', 'temp', 'binary'])
df = df.set_index('utctime')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df2 = df.loc[df['binary']==1]
date = df2.index.date
grouped = df2.groupby(['category', date])
result = grouped['binary'].agg(
    lambda x: (x.index[-1]-x.index[0])/pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))
print(result)
```

yields

```
category            
a         2014-10-24    166.683333
c         2014-10-25    333.350000
e         2014-10-26    166.666667
Name: binary, dtype: float64
```

Comment: a bit more idiomatic instead of the agg to do: ``(grouped.last()-grouped.first())/pd.Timedelta('1m')``, might be faster as well, though YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Indeed that would be much better except that -- unless I'm missing something -- the `grouped.last()` and `grouped.first()` DataFrames only contain the date, not the Timestamps. So taking the difference of those dates would always result in 0.

Comment: I added an answer. No way to group AND perform this type of calc (mainly because the grouping zonks the freq), but just adding a column solves the problem.